# Get session value in Application_End function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc 4 in my project. I am showing 404 page error in Application_End the view is loading successfully. The issue is when the error (view not fond) is occurring in application_end function i have different views of 404 error for Admin and user, so i want to get to know the userId which is stored as a session before loading the view of 404 so that i can load exact view (whether it is of user or admin).

Comment: Are you aware that application_end is fired when the application.. well.. ends? No page can be displayed. You might want to rephrase you question.

Comment: Yes, I know i am application_end works when the application end. and i guess in Application _end i will get the error code of 404. I am pasting the source code here.

Comment: protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {          
            if (Response.StatusCode == 404)// 
            {          
                var rd = new RouteData();
                rd.DataTokens["area"] = "Error"; 
                rd.Values["controller"] = "User";
                rd.Values["action"] = "PAgeError"; 

                IController c = new HomeController();
                c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
            }
        }

Comment: Think about it - this event is fired when your application ends. There is no user - or request - on the other side. It's just the IIS. You are actually "Responding" to no one (I believe that will result in an error). There is no Request-->Respond process here.

Comment: I have sent you the working source code of mine. whenever i get the error PageError view (customized view) will be open. anyways leave it i manage to work this functionality using cookies.  Thank you for giving your time.